# Keeping a views state

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an app that filters out objects from a DB based on a simple form with select options, with each change in the form I get a list from the server with the filtered objects.

When the list returns, I update another view with the list of objects, so the user can tap on the List nav button and see what is filtered so far.

When the user goes back to the Filter nav option, the form has lost the state is was in, or lost the options selected and is blank again. I never submit the form as such.

How do you keep the form to stay the way it was left?

This is my form:

```
       <form id="filter_form" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags.tags.objects | groupBy:'category.name'">
                <div class="item item-divider">
                    {{ key }}
                </div>
                <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-repeat="(item_key, item) in value | groupBy:'subcategory.name'">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        {{ item_key }}
                    </div>
                    <select>
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option ng-repeat="option in item">
                            {{ option.description }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
              </label>      
            </div>
        </form>
```

Form looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list">
        <form id="filter_form" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" novalidate class="simple-form">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags.tags.objects | groupBy:'category.name'">
                <div class="item item-divider">
                    {{ key }}
                </div>
                <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-repeat="(item_key, item) in value | groupBy:'subcategory.name'">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        {{ item_key }}
                    </div>
                    <select ng-model="tag" ng-options="option.description for option in item">
              </label>      
            </div>
        </form>
        <a class="button button-block button-positive" href="/#/tab/filter/advanced">Advanced</a>

    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: So you want to remember the selected item and set it again when the view containing the form is loaded?

Comment: Yes exactly, I did not think it would have to be set again though

Comment: how about [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) then?

Comment: Im not sure how I would use this, Im confused as my form is generated in a for loop

Comment: You can just put tag into a service/value. See my answer for more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61485/discussion-between-harry-and-s-hoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put tag into a value:

```
yourModule.value('tag', {data: null});
```

in the controller:

```
yourModule.controller('formCtrl', function($scope, tag) {
    $scope.tag = {data: null};
    if(tag)
        $scope.tag = tag;
    else
        formData = tag;
    // rest of your code
});
```

in the html, change the select´s ng-model to tag.data:

```
<select ng-model="tag.data" ng-options="option.description for option in item">
```

see this (simplified) [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1M5In5pE1o3ExFtoN6r?p=preview)

Comment: If I understand this correctly I can make the $scope.tag = [{"name":"Fruit_Type","value":"0"},{"name":"Leaves_Arrangment","value":"?"},{"name":"Leaves_Margin","value":"?"},{"name":"Leaves_Type","value":"?"}] and the form should be filled in right? But it is not

Comment: tag (or, in this case, tag.data) is the option you selected. The idea is that tag and $scope.tag refer to the same object meaning if one gets updated, the other does, too. So when you select an option, it ends up in the service and next time you load your controller with the form, it goes back to what it was before.